# Parrot Linux boots to black screen with blinking underscore: Can get shell with ctrl + alt + F1

Tags: linux, boot, partition, boot-loader, parrotsec

So I recently moved around the Linux swap partition and resized the root partition of my Parrot installation on my hard disk to increase available space. After applying the edits with GParted I haven't been able to boot with a graphical interface. Instead after initializing the screen turns black with a blinking cursor in the top left corner. From what I presume, this is associated with an error in GRUB. For the past two weeks, I've looked at various options over how to deal with the problem, but have found no solution. After getting a shell with Ctrl+Alt+F1, I've ran update scripts with apt-get, grub, and initramfs. There is also a possible error having to do with the segmentation of arrays. Long story short I was also experiencing failure in one of my SATA cables connecting to my CDROM drive. After replacing it, the `ata1: error:` messages no longer appeared, along with the `mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically`, however after running the `bootinfoscript` as suggested by various sources, the issue still persists. I'm at a loss here as I've tried various ideas yet have seen no results.

Here are some resources for the issue:

`bootinfoscript`:

```
Boot Info Script 0.76      [13 April 2017]

Identifying MBRs...
Computing Partition Table of /dev/sda...
Searching sda1 for information... 
Searching sda2 for information... 
Searching sda4 for information... 
                  Boot Info Script 0.76      [13 April 2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Parrot GNU/Linux 4.0
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   697,952,255   697,950,208  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         697,952,256   697,972,735        20,480  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       1,748,725,760 1,953,525,167   204,799,408  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364   ext4       
/dev/sda2        bff285cd-4db4-4ad7-8656-e86cf811808e   swap       
/dev/sda4        8583fa2e-35fe-4064-a277-201e72982afc   ext4       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun  3 01:37 ata-ASUS_DRW-24F1ST_a_S10K68EF300420 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun  3 01:37 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA100_Y3GYH74NS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA100_Y3GYH74NS-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA100_Y3GYH74NS-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA100_Y3GYH74NS-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun  3 01:37 wwn-0x5000039ff7cd67ef -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 wwn-0x5000039ff7cd67ef-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 wwn-0x5000039ff7cd67ef-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 01:37 wwn-0x5000039ff7cd67ef-part4 -> ../../sda4

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1        /var/lib/docker/overlay2 ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1        /var/lib/docker/plugins  ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=C
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
fi
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/parrot-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png; then
  true
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Parrot GNU/Linux' --class parrot --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 root=UUID=b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364 ro noautomount quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Parrot GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
    menuentry 'Parrot GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.16.0-parrot12-amd64' --class parrot --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64-advanced-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 root=UUID=b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364 ro noautomount quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Parrot GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class parrot --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64-recovery-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64 root=UUID=b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364 ro single noautomount
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Parrot GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.16.0-parrot5-amd64' --class parrot --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64-advanced-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.16.0-parrot5-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64 root=UUID=b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364 ro noautomount quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Parrot GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.16.0-parrot5-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class parrot --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64-recovery-b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.16.0-parrot5-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64 root=UUID=b7ff9eea-13c4-4b30-8104-b41cc3258364 ro single noautomount
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
/dev/sda2 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 187.522518158 = 201.350770688  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             3
   4.466430664 = 4.795793408    boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 190.794677734 = 204.864225280  boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64             1
 116.404052734 = 124.987899904  boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64              1
 190.794677734 = 204.864225280  vmlinuz                                        1
 116.404052734 = 124.987899904  vmlinuz.old                                    1
   7.262573242 = 7.798128640    boot/initrd.img-4.12.0-parrot6-amd64.old-dkms  3
 131.342136383 = 141.027545088  boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-parrot4-amd64.dpkg-bak  2
 185.904907227 = 199.613874176  boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-parrot4-amd64.old-dkms  1
  19.698547363 = 21.151154176   boot/initrd.img-4.14.0-parrot13-amd64.old-dkms  5
  55.503704071 = 59.596648448   boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-parrot17-amd64.old-dkms  1
  91.322883606 = 98.057199616   boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot12-amd64          2
  85.414760590 = 91.713400832   boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64           4
  91.322883606 = 98.057199616   initrd.img                                     2
  85.414760590 = 91.713400832   initrd.img.old                                 4

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** After applying the edits with GParted I haven't been able to boot with a graphical interface. Instead after initializing the screen turns black with a blinking cursor in the top left corner. **

I have similar issue, not identical, You may wanna try this:
[Fixing the black screen after grub boot-up (screen/video settings mismatch)]

Comment: Link: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842